# Okular not printing the right paperformat?

Tags: printing, pdf, media, okular

Okular does not communicate properly with Canon MF 3010 concerning papersize?
I try to print a pdf-document, papersize a5. Okular selects a4 paper in printing, resulting in misplaced text.
Evince, e. g., does the same a5-paper-pdf-job on the same printer without any misplacement, selecting the right paper-size.
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; LaTeX-produced pdf-document; TeXLive 2022.

Comment: Did you already do this? Open `File -> Print` in Okular. Click on `Properties` button right beside the name of the printer.
Select paper size.

Comment: Yes! I did. But it didn't do the job.

Comment: By any chance are you using Okular installed from snap? If so, try the apt version

Comment: My okular version is ,Version 21.12.3'. Trying to update using an apt-command I get the answer that I do have the latest version. Any clues?

Comment: Ubuntu does not provider major version revisions in a particular release to maintain stability. If you need a later version of Okular, you will have to update to a later version of Ubuntu (or use snap, which is often buggy)

Comment: My Ubuntu is the latest LTS-version of Ubuntu. Any help to install Okular from an debian.tar-file is appriciated.

Comment: Just use `sudo apt install okular` to install a recent, working version (but not the latest one). Is there any specific reason you need the latest version of Okular? If you always want to use the latest version of every software you use, then you will have to switch to a rolling release like Manjaro, EndeavourOS or Arch Linux

Comment: OK, that's the way my (older) version of Okular is installed. So the installed version of Okular is not the problem?